# NetBeans Run in external terminal

Tags: c++, netbeans, gdb

I recently installed Arch Linux with XFCE4 desktop environment.  I use NetBeans as my IDE.  I want to debug a program through NetBeans in an external terminal, but it won't do that.  It does not recognize XFCE4 Terminal, and will not run gdb within it.

Is there a way that I can permanently set NetBeans to debug/run my programs in XFCE4 Terminal (aka, add it to "run in external terminal")?

Also, I'm using NetBeans 8.0-1, and gcc 4.9 (all the latest and greatest with Arch!  :), if that helps at all.

If you need any more details, please ask.

Comment: What was the magic to add another new terminal type to External Terminal Type?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing Konsole (a KDE terminal), I was able to make it work!  Using XFCE as my default still, though, since it's a really nice terminal.

Gnome terminal did not work.  When I opened it, it did not show any text, and I couldn't verify input or output as a result.

Comment: further details of configuration will be appreciated

Comment: -  64 bit Architecture
-  i3 processor
-  XFCE4 Desktop Environment
-  Arch Linux (latest)
-  NetBeans 8.0-1, With Java 1.7
-  gcc 4.9

Mabey if you ask what you need specifically, I can give you what you need...  I can't think of any other relevant information.  NOTE:  I inserted 0x0A, but I guess newlines don't work well with this poesting site.